# Cycle trough URLs from a txt

Tags: python, selenium

This is my first question so please bear with me (I have googled this and I did not find anything)

I'm making a program which goes to a url, clicks a button, checks if the page gets forwarded and if it does saves that url to a file.

So far I've got the first two steps done but I'm having some issues.

I want Selenium to repeat this process with multiple urls (if possible, multiple at a time).
I have all the urls in a txt called `output.txt`

At first I did

```
url_list = https://example.com
```

to see if my program even worked, and it did however I am stuck on how to get it to go to the next URL in the list and I am unable to find anything on the internet which helps me.

This is my code so far

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

url_list = "C\\user\\python\\output.txt"

def site():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\python\\chromedriver")
    driver.get(url_list)
    send = driver.find_element_by_id("NextButton")
    send.click()

    if (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='Error']")):
        print("Error class found")
```

I have no idea as to how I'd get selenium to go to the first url in the list then go onto the second one and so forth. 
If anyone would be able to help me I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you assumed the name of the file containing the url, is a url. You need to open the file first and build the url list.
According to the docs https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/, `get` expect a url, not a file path.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
with open("C\\user\\python\\output.txt") as f:
 url_list = f.read().split('\n')

def site():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\python\\chromedriver")
    for url in url_list:
       driver.get(url)
       send = driver.find_element_by_id("NextButton")
       send.click()

       if (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='Error']")):
          print("Error class found")
```

Comment: It would be prudent to wrap the code inside the loop with a try...except clause so that if anything happens, it does not hinder the other links from getting scrapped.